# How to get value from a sheet to another sheet with a criteria in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have one Google sheet table with two sheets.

First one (Sheets 3)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjAh2.png)

Second One (Shhet 4)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJlx7.png)

I need to write a formula to fill the C column in Sheet 4 taking values from Sheet 3. Now I set it right values for better understanding my question, but it has ti be done by formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `XLOOKUP()` function. Try-

```
=IF(D2="","",XLOOKUP(D2,B:B,A:A,""))
```

To refer other sheet, just use sheet name in front of range.

```
=IF(D2="","",XLOOKUP(D2,'Sheet 3'!B:B,'Sheet 3'A:A,""))
```

For dynamic spill array, use `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function. Try-

```
=MAP(D2:D12,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="","",XLOOKUP(x,B:B,A:A,""))))
```

[image]

Comment: @ichark Glad to know! If it works, then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Comment: Sure, I have done it